# Return list with more than one value stored in a dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary defined as follow: `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` and I want to filter so that it will only entries where `List<Int>` has more than 1 value in it.

The code below builds my dictionary correctly (thanks to Andrew Whitaker)

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> fieldNameList = 
    Mapping.Select(m => m.FieldName)
           .Select((c, i) => new { Value = c, Index = i })
           .GroupBy(o => o.Value, o => o.Index)
           .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

but now I need to filter it down so that only list with more than one items in it will be included in the final dictionary.

Would you mind explaining the extra filter as I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I added `.Where(m => m.Value.Count > 1)` of the existing query thinking this would do the trick, but it's giving an "implicit convertion" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest you can apply a filter is after grouping and before creating a dictionary:

```
.GroupBy(o => o.Value, o => o.Index)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

This should not need any explanation; it's most efficient in that it avoids adding the items you don't want in the dictionary in the first place.

If you wanted to keep the single-item lists but filter them out only some of the time, you 'd instead need to filter on the dictionary with

```
dict.Where(p => p.Value.Count > 1)
```

Your original attempt

```
.ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList())
.Where(m => m.Value.Count > 1);
```

did not work because, even though it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do, the type of the result produced by `Where` would be `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>`. However, you are trying to assign this value to a variable typed as a concrete dictionary, which is a special case of an enumerable list of key-value pairs and the compiler has to stop you from doing that in order to guarantee type safety.

If you changed the type of `fieldNameList` to the above then this line would compile, but you would not be able to use the `IDictionary<K, V>` interface later on.

Comment: A quick question, would using `.Any()` not be more efficient than `.Count()`?

Comment: Damn, that was quick!! :)... Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. Frustrating as I'd swear I tried that as well, but I obviously did it wrong! Thanks again!.

Comment: @DavidPilkington: It needs to be greater than 1, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidPilkington if using `Any()`, it should be `.Skip(1).Any()`, looks like it's better but somehow it's not really, I tested 2 code and looks like the `.Count()` version is even faster? weird.

Comment: @Jon, the explanation I was asking for was why it didn't work the way I did it i.e. putting the .Where after the ToDictionary but thanks for solving this out for me. Most appreciated!

Comment: @Thierry: I 'll update the answer, hang on a sec, I 'm trying to find something to refer David to.

Comment: @DavidPilkington: Please take a look at the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913573/50079), my point is that starting enumeration over the grouped results *requires* that the group be fully materialized first (otherwise opportunity for horrible performance), so the information needed to get the count in constant time is already there. Therefore it would be "silly" for the BCL to not take advantage of it as it does with arrays and lists, and indeed it does.

Comment: @KingKing: We have had this conversation before :-) -- check the link above.

Comment: @Jon yes, really interesting, I even had to use closure to avoid calling `g.Count()` 2 times before, now I can freely use it without any fear about bad performance :)

Comment: @KingKing: To be fair there is no guarantee anywhere that getting the count is constant time, it's all based on common sense. If the code that counts is performance critical you would be fully justified to take explicit measures.

Comment: @Jon I think as long as the `g` is `IGrouping`, it's safe to use, otherwise such as `IEnumerable` of course we should not use `Count`, I believe it's true for the `IGrouping`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to filter the dictionary as you are building it, but if you need both the non-filtered and the filtered dictionary, or if you need to filter an existing dictionary, you can again call `.ToDictionary`.

As Jon explained `Where` on a dictionary returns a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>`, and you only need to separate the key and the value of the pair, into a key and value of a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> resultDict = 
                       sourceDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Count > 1)
                                 .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```